# Expression of type Iteratee[Array[Byte], StatusHeader] doesn't conform to expected type Accumulater[Byte,Result] in Play scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, casting, type-conversion

```
class AuthorizedFilter extends EssentialFilter  {

  private def authorizationRequired(request: RequestHeader) = {
    val clientId = request.headers.get("clientId");
    val id = "74f6df0452";  //to match with clientID.Block remaining request
    clientId match {
      case Some(id) =>
        true;
      case _ =>
        false;
    }

  }

  def apply(next: EssentialAction):EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
     def apply(request: RequestHeader)  = {
      println("result...",request.headers.get("clientId"));

      if(!authorizationRequired(request)) {
        *Iteratee.ignore[Array[Byte]].map(_ => Results.forbidden())*
      }
      else {
        println("YOU are authorized!!")
        next(request)
      }
      }
  }
}
```

The above filter was added to block all the requests where clientID is not matched. I got error message in *Iteratee.ignore[Array[Byte]].map(_ => Results.forbidden())*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you took a piece of code from an older version of play framework and you are now using a version >= 2.5. You need to replace the line `Iteratee...` with:

```
Accumulator.done(Results.forbidden())
```

cf [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#More-powerful-filters)